# How is $\cos(x)={e^{jx}+e^{-jx}\over 2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to prove the following equation?

What is proof for $$\cos(x)=\dfrac{e^{jx}+e^{-jx}}{ 2} \qquad \qquad j=\sqrt{-1}$$

Comment: That depends on your definition of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: What math do you know? If you know about uniqueness of solutions to ODEs, you could check that both functions satisfy $y'' = -y$, $y(0)= 1$, $y'(0) = 0$.

Comment: What is the definition of $e^{jx}$ ?

Comment: On the other hand, if you know about complex taylor series,  you can just check term-by-term equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{jx} = \cos x+j\sin x$$

$$e^{-jx} = \cos x-j\sin x$$

$$e^{jx}+e^{-jx} = (\cos x+j\sin x)+(\cos x-j\sin x) = 2\cos x$$

Comment: how is eix=cosx+isinx ?

Comment: This is [Euler formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: You can examine the Taylor expansions of each term to see the equality.

Comment: @AmruthA what is $e^{jx}$ if anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Euler formula, $e^{ix}=cos(x)+i*sin(x)$. To derive this formula, you can use the taylor expansions of $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$.